# How to change background color of menubutton in xul

Tags: css, xul

I want to change the background color of the menu-button in toolbarbutton.

I applied the following code but it was not working.

```
<toolbarbutton id="search" background-color="red" type="menu-button" label="Search"  width="83" height="25" oncommand="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();">
    <menupopup>
        <menuitem label="Web" value="webs" onclick="webSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
        <menuitem label="Images" value="images" onclick="imageSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
        <menuitem label="News" value="news" onclick="newsSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
        <menuitem label="Video" value="videos" onclick="videoSearch();event.stopPropagation();"/>
    </menupopup>
</toolbarbutton>
```

Comment: I know nothing about XUL but your attempt is definitively *not* CSS.

Comment: ya but can be done through css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can have background color of the button. Please check with this, you can change the color of the text not the button color.

I would suggest you to have a customized toolbar button.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/custom_toolbar_button
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/toolbarbutton

The above links will help you to fix your problem.

```
<toolbar>
  <toolbarbutton label="Checkbox Type" type="checkbox" image="firefox.png"/>
  <toolbarbutton label="Menu Type" type="menu" popup="button-popup" style="font: bold 11px Verdana, sans-serif !important; color:#327DC7; background-color=#327DC7;" />
  <toolbarbutton label="Menu Button Type" type="menu-button" popup="button-popup" image="firefox.png"/>
  <menupopup id="button-popup">
    <menuitem label="Item 1"/>
    <menuitem label="Item 2"/>
    <menuitem label="Item 3"/>
  </menupopup>
</toolbar>
```

To know more about the toolbar menu button CSS features, you can check the Firefox dafult settings in the installation directory in your system. For example, like this:

> jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files/Mozilla%20Firefox/chrome/classic.jar!/skin/classic/global/toolbarbutton.css

Answer (score 3):

You should use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS):

```
<toolbarbutton style="background-color: red;">
```

Comment: It does for me - the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: actually i have a menubutton may be its not working bcoz of that

Comment: At [Writing Skinnable XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Skinnable_XUL_and_CSS#Writing_Skinnable_XUL) they say: *style="..." is prohibited in XUL files without approval*. It's possible that you are only allowed to use an external CSS file.

Comment: @Álvaro: Have a look at the date - that document is from 2000. Handling of inline styles has been added around 2005. It's not recommendable of course and using external CSS files is better. But for quickly testing out things it should work.

Comment: @gardi: No, that doesn't matter - adding a `style` attributes works regardless.